# Posting image to server using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am just trying post an image to a url using php .I am using ajax and jquery also
Can anyone help me what could be the issue.Here is the ajax and php  code snippet.

```
$("#imgupload").click(function(){
    var time = DateNow();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>test/test_send_message",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: $("#imgfile").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log("time");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(){
                console.log("error");       
            }       
        })

});

php code below

function test_send_message(){

    //image upload
    $tid = $_POST['tid'];
    $mytpe = "img";
    $image = $_POST['imgfile'];

    $sid = $_POST['sid'];
    $mytpe = "txt";
    $message = $_POST['chatinput'];


    $url = 'https://api.test.com/test/prod/v1';
    $headers = array (
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the problem is? Any errors?

Comment: You can't use post for a image file you have to use $_FILES

Comment: Problem is i  am not able to upload after using $_FILES also thanks for your suggestion